# DataFrame grouping and iteration with reduction requiring knowlage of the next row

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following dataframe:

```
First = ['mark']*4 + ['phil']*4 + ['maria']
BeginDT = ['4/1/2016', '5/1/2016', '6/1/2016', '7/1/2016', '3/1/2016', '4/1/2016', '6/1/2016', '7/1/2016', '3/1/2016']
EndDT = ['4/30/2016', '5/31/2016', '6/30/2016', '7/31/2016',  '3/31/2016', '4/30/2016', '6/30/2016', '7/31/2016', '3/31/2016']
df = pd.DataFrame({'First':First, 'BeginDT':BeginDT, 'EndDT':EndDT} ) ; df
```

I'm trying to iterate over each row of the datafame for each person. I need to retain the end date for each person, compare this end date to the next start date, to see if the time periods are continuous. If so, continue in the loop, other wise output the continuous portions.  I've tried Series.shift(), some loops with flow controls, building iterators, but I'm too new to python and computer programing to figure it out.  Please help.  Thank you in advance!

Desired result

first, EpiStart, EpiEnd
mark , 4/1/2016 , 7/31/2016 | because it's really one long episode
phil, 3/1/2016 , 4/30/2016 | because there two episodes
phil, 6/1/2016, 7/31/2016
maria, '3/1/2016', '3/31/2016'

Comment: Sorry, I should have added pandas as a tag.